# How can I use the default dialog icons in my custom Blackberry popup dialog?

Tags: blackberry, dialog, icons, look-and-feel

I'm writing a custom dialog window to display the status of a long operation, and would like to use the little timer icon (the little square clock on OS >= 4.6) that's used in the BB native dialogs.

How can I use this graphic within my dialog?

I'm already familiar with layout managers and such, I just don't know where the bitmap is, or if there's an API call to get the default theme icons like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under the `Bitmap` class there's an [`HOURGLASS` constant](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#HOURGLASS) defined that can be used with the [`getPredefinedBitmap()` method](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#getPredefinedBitmap%28int%29).

Example:

```
Manager.add(new BitmapField(Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.HOURGLASS)));
```

This was pretty well hidden within the javadocs, so I figured I'd answer my own question in case anyone else needs to know.